# Complexity of a problem related to 3D matching?

Tags: computational-complexity, reference-request

Given a set of triples of a base set $S$, find a subset of triples such that each element in $S$ appears exactly in one triple. This problem is NP-complete by reduction from NP-complete problem 3D Matching.

I'm interested in the complexity of related problem. What is the complexity of finding a subset of triples such that each element in $S$ appears exactly in two triples?

Has this problem been studied in the literature? I'd greatly appreciate pointing me to references.

Comment: The problem seems to admit a fairly straightforward reduction from 3D matching.

Comment: Which reduction do you have in mind for NP-hardness?